# For loop over multiple files in a folder

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I'm attempting to extract a single value from each file contained in folder A. The code runs without throwing an error but returns an empty array for Mfinal. Does anyone see where things might be going wrong?

```
Mfinal=[]

path = r'C:Desktop/thesis/hrfiles/A' 
all_files = glob.glob(path + '/*.csv')

for filename in all_files:
    df=pd.dataframe(filename)
    mass=df[9]
    m=mass[-1]
    Mfinal.append(m)
```

Comment: Try pd.read_csv(filename)

Comment: Perhaps the glob doesn't capture anything? What is `len(all_files)`?

Comment: What exactly is mass=df[9] supposed to do?

Comment: @MitchellOlislagers pd.read_csv did not work, it says there is an error tokenizing data. Also, mass=df[9] is meant to make an array of the column 9.

Comment: @Maksim it turns out as I learned from the below answer all_files has length zero.

Answer (score 2):

Even if `m == None`, `Mfinal` cannot be empty if `for` loops without any errors.
So, the reasonable suspicion here is that `all_files` is empty.
Thus, nothing is found by `glob.glob`.

If you are on Window, try

```
path = r'C:\Desktop\thesis\hrfiles\A' 
all_files = glob.glob(path + '\*.csv')
```

Comment: You can prove this is the issue by printing "len(all_files)"

Comment: This was indeed the issue. I am on mac, and have tried altering the filepath to see if my system just can't find what to put in all_files without any luck so far.

Comment: @lauchter The root path of Mac is `/` not `C`. So, try `/Users/[username]/Desktop....`.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with ghchoi on the initial path here. Fairly sure there needs to be `\` following `C:`.